# How to handle client authentication for secure web service in Delphi?

Tags: web-services, delphi, sharepoint, authentication, delphi-2010

I have a SharePoint server running on my network and I am trying to build an app in Delphi which allows me to access the various [SharePoint Web Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms479390%28v=office.12%29.aspx) hosted there.

Running my app on the same network as the SharePoint server works fine, however, when I attempt to run it on a VM which is not part of the same Domain I can't get authenticated. I was looking for some advice as to how I should be handling authentication for this type of scenario, more specifically, should I be prompting the user for their credentials or is there some built in security model I can use for this?

Ideally I would like to try avoid dealing with Usernames & Passwords in my app and let the OS handle that sort of thing, however, at the moment I can't seem to see any other way around this.

Comment: First you need to know which authentication methods are supported by SharePoint (Basic, Digest, NTLM, Kerberos for example) and which one is active at the moment. NTLM does not require user interaction, but the other domain needs to be 'trusted' iirc. Basic auth requires that the app sends user name / password so user interaction is required if the passwords are not hardcoded somewhere.

Comment: @mjn From my understanding what happens is when I attempt to access the web service I get a 401 and the server should respond with a WWW-Authenticate header indicating which type(s) of authentication it supports. So is it at this point I would need to intercept this and prompt the user for credentials? The goal here is to allow users to open up files from any SharePoint server regardless of where they run my app, therefore, there could possibly be scenarios where domains aren't "trusted" and are going to require impersonation.

Comment: Basically this is correct, but to provide the credentials lots of code and client/server interaction steps can be required, which is much easier to solve with existing code. Internet Direct (Indy) supports NTLM so it will take care of credentials in the background when the HTTP POST is sent. Just add the necessary auth handler units to the project (Indy self-registers them automatically) and use the debugger to see how far it works.

Comment: @mjn I am currently using Indy and I have added the `IdAuthenticationNTLM` unit and it does handle all the NTLM stuff if I am connected to the network. However, like I say when I am not on the network I just get 401's as my credentials would be wrong. I would love to re-use existing code to handle this (e.g. prompting user for credentials and sending across the wire) however the problem is I don't know how to do it. I will attempt to include the `IdAuthenticationDigest` & `IdAuthenticationSSPI` units to see if it automatically detects this and prompts.

Comment: You need to verify that the server is configured to accept these auth types.

Comment: @mjn if I pass my credentials across the authentication works ok, however, that's if I hard-code them into my app. The authentication problem isn't actually accessing the file itself (as Windows security kicks in and prompts the user for their details anyway) it's when I try to access the Web Service through code I get a 401, it's at this point I need to somehow tell the server my app is authorised to access the service.

Comment: I downloaded http://webservicestudio.codeplex.com/ and it demonstrates the same problem. Downloading the WSDL from a machine on the network works fine, however, running it on the VM off the network gives me a 401 error. This is the problem I have at the moment, I need to know how I can authenticate the request.

Comment: Do you know about http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_Directory#Trust ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some investigation, for my particular scenario I decided that the best approach would be to use [WinINet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383630%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). I chose this approach over [Indy](http://www.indyproject.org/index.en.aspx) because after some thorough investigation I found Indy did have some bugs & also it didn't have all the authentication handling we needed built in.

WinINet supports prompting for credentials & automatically authenticating across the wire. See [Handling Authentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384220%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).